# Fano blow ups of $\mathbb CP^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fano-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth complex variety. Is it always possible to find an embedding $\varphi: X\to \mathbb CP^n$ for some $n$, such that the blow up of $\mathbb CP^n$ at $\varphi(X)$ is a Fano variety?

Let us call the above class of varieties $F$-embeddable. How large is this class? How large is its complement?

Comment: I believe this fails for every curve with $g\geq 2$.  By Proposition 5.2(ii) of this -- https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602644 -- the blowing up is Fano only if the maximal slope on $X$ of an invertible subsheaf of the normal bundle $N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}$ is strictly less than the fraction $\text{deg}_X (T_{\mathbb{P}^n}|_X)/\text{rank}(N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n})$.  If $T_X$ is negative, then $\text{deg}_X (N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n})$ is strictly larger than $\text{deg}_X(T_{\mathbb{P}^n}|_X)$.  The fraction is smaller than the slope of $N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}$, so this fails even in the semistable case.

Comment: Many thanks Jason! (I wonder if it is a coincidence that $g\ge 2$ means general type).

Comment: Actually, I see now that this is already a problem if $g(X)$ equals $1$.  Then $\text{deg}_X(N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n})$ equals $\text{deg}_X(T_{\mathbb{P}^n}|X)$, so that the fraction equals the slope of $N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}$.  However, the necessary condition is that the maximal slope of an invertible sheaf is bounded below this slope, not just for $X$, but also for covers $C\to X$.  As explained in Corollary 6.9, that is impossible.

Comment: @Jason: There must be something wrong. The blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^3$ along a curve of bidegree $(p,q)$, with $p,q\leq 3$, is Fano.

Comment: @abx.  You are correct: I was misreading the formula for that fraction.  The denominator is $\text{rank}(N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n})-1$, not $\text{rank}(N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n})$.

Comment: I corrected the argument in the answer below.  The argument applies if $g(X) \gg 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note.** My comment above was wrong; I had the wrong denominators. When you correct the denominators, the formula gives an asymptotic result.

In my comment I wrote the wrong formula for the denominator of that fraction.  The correct statement is that the blowing up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ along a smooth subvariety $X$ of pure dimension $d$ is Fano if and only if there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for every irreducible curve $B$ and for every nonconstant morphism $u:B\to \mathbb{P}^n$ both, $$\bullet \ \ \text{deg}_B (g^{-1}(X))  \leq \frac{1}{c-1}\left(\text{deg}_B(g^*T_{\mathbb{P}^n}) - \epsilon \ \text{deg}_B (g^*H)\right)\  \text{ if } g(B)\not\subset X, $$ $$\bullet \ \ \mu_B^1(g^*N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}) \leq \frac{1}{c-1}\left( \text{deg}_B(g^*T_{\mathbb{P}^n}) - \epsilon \ \text{deg}_B (g^*H) \right)\ \text{ if } g(B)\subset X,$$
where $c$ equals the codimension $n-d$, and where $\mu^1_B(g^*N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n})$ denotes the maximal slope of an invertible subsheaf of $g^*N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}$.  In characteristic $0$, up to replacing $B$ by a cover and replacing $\epsilon$ by a smaller positive number such as $\epsilon/2$, we may replace $\mu^1_B$ by the maximal slope of any locally free subsheaf of $g^*N_{X/\mathbb{P}^n}$ of positive rank, cf. Corollary 6.9 of the link above.

**Claim.** In characteristic $0$, for every $d$, there are only finitely many deformation types of $F$-embeddable varieties of dimension $d$.

**Proof**
If $X$ is a linear subvariety, then the blowing up is Fano.  Thus assume that $X$ is not a linear subvariety, e.g., this holds if $X$ is not abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^d$.

In that case, there exists a $2$-secant line $B$ to $X$ that is not contained in $X$.  Then $\text{deg}_B(g^{-1}(X))$ equals $2$, whereas the fraction equals $(n+1-\epsilon)/(n-d-1)$.  This can only be Fano if $n\leq 2d+2$.  Thus, for $n\geq 2d+3$, the blowing up is not Fano.  In characteristic $0$, Kollár-Miyaoka-Mori proved that there are only finitely many deformation types of Fano manifolds of dimension $\leq n_0$ for each $n_0$.  Setting $n_0=2d+2$, it follows that for every integer $d>0$, there are only finitely many deformation types of smooth projective variety of dimension $d$ that admit a closed immersion $\phi:X\to \mathbb{P}^n$ for which the blowing up is Fano. **QED**

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I have a question concerning lines -4-5 (I don't understand something). It looks to me that you claim that a blow up of $\mathbb P^5$ in any curve is not Fano? Is not the  blow up in a line in $\mathbb P^n$ Fano for any $n$? (or the line is the only exception?)

Comment: I edited my answer to address your question.